# Bookdown: create file according to source Rmd filename

Tags: r, bookdown

For each `Rmd` file I want to create file (directory) that is named according to `Rmd` file.

Example `_bookdown.yml`:

```
rmd_files: [
  "index.Rmd",
  "intro.Rmd",
  "analysis.Rmd"]
```

For each `Rmd` (probably using `before_chapter_script`) I want to create output directory:

```
./index/
./intro/
./analysis/
```

**Question:** How to extract `Rmd` filename using `bookdown`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I interpret your qn correctly, here is how you can create those output directories by including the following code in index.Rmd or _main.Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Anon"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
output: bookdown::gitbook
---

```
cfg <- yaml::yaml.load_file("_bookdown.yml")
invisible(lapply(gsub(".Rmd", "", cfg$rmd_files), dir.create))
```
````